# Is there a way to globally catch unhandled promise exceptions in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exception, promise, react-redux

I tried using the componentDidCatch, but it looks like that hook is only for actual errors in rendering components. Promises can happen in one of the component hierarchies but don't actually get thrown until later.

I also wrapped a tryCatch around my function that does the initial render of the app, but that fails to catch the exception too.(for the reason I think)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can attach [onunhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection) event to top most component componentDidDount method.

```
class TopComponent extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
    window.onunhandledrejection = (err) => {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I also listen to the onError one as well?